# How to echo this function..It's not working

Tags: php, echo

i have this function..what i want is to echo this..but it's not working

```
function chkU() {

    if(!$getD == null){
        $dateC = $getDate;

    } else{
        $dateC = date("Y-m-d");

    }

}
```

**This is where i'm trying to echo**

```
$ec = file_get_html('dir/'.chkDateUrl().'/doc.html');
```

Thank you!

Comment: In the future being a bit more descriptive (more than it's not working) will help you get answers to nontrivial questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return a value so try this:

```
function chkU() {

    if(!$getD == null){
        return $dateC = $getDate;
    } else{
        return $dateC = date("Y-m-d");
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks..btwn i  have small problem in this function..i'm passing value in url and in the function i'm checking whether the value is passed or not..but it's not working..any idea?

Comment: @jehan In this example you're not passing anything to the function! But if you want to check if a variable is set or is empty use: isset() | empty() you can look them up in the manual